# Upstart problems with clone using CLONE_NEWPID and expect fork

Tags: upstart

I have a binary which looks something like the following:

```
int RealMain() {
  ... runs forever ...
}

int main() {
  clone(RealMain, ..., CLONE_NEWPID /*clone flags*/, ...);
  _exit(0);
}
```

The idea is to launch a process which launches the actual process via clone() and exits.  The reason for this model is the "CLONE_NEWPID" flag.  I need the app to run in a separate PID namespace.  Therefore, the actual application process needs to be created via clone using the CLONE_NEWPID flag.

When I launch this binary from command line, everything works well.  But when I launch it through Upstart, the clone() fails with errno set to EPERM and the new PID namespace is never created.  I'm using "expect fork" in the Upstart config because of the clone() call above.  That way I can associate liveness to the lifetime of the child process executing RealMain().

```
expect fork
respawn
```

I'm wondering if there is some bad interaction between the implementation of "expect fork" and the use of CLONE_NEWPID which creates a new PID namespace.  I found the following source about "expect fork" and ptrace issues, but haven't found someone else reporting a problem with CLONE_NEWPID:

https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-q-upstart-overcome-ptrace-limitations

Thanks